# Find index of when 0 sandwiched by non-zero values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 12 integers that correspond to values for each month in a year.

I want to find the indices (months) where there is a value of 0 sandwiched by a non-zero value. By sandwiched I mean there is non-zero on both sides (so it could never be first or last value in list)

So in an example of:

```
values = [0,0,3,0,5,6,0,8,0,1,0,0]
```

it would return the indices `3,6` because `values[3]` and `values[6]` have values of 0 and index +- 1 are non-zero.

My basic idea is to load 3 integers at a time and check if `i[1] == 1` and `i[0] != 0` and `i[2] != 0` but this seems like an inefficient solution

Comment: We love that you're here and we want to see your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Only 3 and 6 not 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
result = []
for i in range(1, len(arr)-1):
    if (arr[i] == 0 and arr[i-1] != 0 and arr[i+1] != 0):
        result.append(i)
print(result) #prints [3, 6, 8]
```

- ***Note: -- As per the logic explained 8 also should be the part of the
  output list.***

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension, but that basically boils down to taking 3 integers. It makes use of the fact that any non zero integer evaluates to `True`.

Note, position 8 also qualifies for the rules.

```
print([i for i in range(1, len(v)-1) if not v[i] and v[i-1] and v[i+1]])

# prints
[3, 6, 8]
```